# Start of Response Audio Cuts Out and Screen Blinks

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, google-assistant-sdk

I just installed Google Assistant on my Raspberry Pi 3B as part of a Magic Mirror project I've been working off and on for the past year or so. I can run the assistant fine, except when it responds the first little bit of the response is cut off.

For example I would ask "*What time is it*" (The time being **10:30 PM** for example) and it would respond "*30 PM.*" Additionally whenever this happens the screen will cut out for just the blink of an eye. Not 100% sure these are related but it feels like more than a coincidence to me.

Any help with this little hiccup would be much appreciated!

Comment: I vaguely recall the Assistant SDK showing the command output in the console when running. Is it showing the full output, or is it also cut off?

Comment: Unfortunately, all I see in the terminal is: when it is triggered, what I say, and when it completes. It doesn't print what it said.

Comment: Is there any of your own code in the mix yet, or is this just using example code from Google? If it's failing with your own code, rule it out with one of Google's examples to see if the same issue occurs.

Comment: As of now I am using someone else's code to integrate it with my mirror, but that doesn't seem to be affecting it because I get the same problem using the demo that comes when you install it on the RPi

Comment: So if code is out of the mix, perhaps there's an issue with insufficient power to the speaker or other parts of your setup, so it's delayed before it can output the audio feed? Are you using a speaker, or line out to something like headphones?

Comment: It is through the HDMI on my screen's built-in speakers

Comment: The RPi3 has a headphone jack. Please try this.

Comment: I guess I'll have to add speakers to my setup. This worked perfectly! Thanks

Comment: Glad that helped. If it works perfectly with the headphone jack, then we at least know there's some potential troubleshooting to be done with the HDMI connection.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the comments, there may be some configuration needed for the HDMI to behave as desired.

Please see the [Audio Configuration](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/audio-config.md) documents for more ideas.